# Why components doesn't show on my shape. I want to place them on a rectangle it disappears and the rectangle only shows?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jlabel

I'm having a really big issue in which when ether I create a `JLabel`, `Jbutton` and so on, it works in terms of showing on screen however when I want to place them on a rectangle it disappears and the rectangle only shows?

With `JLabel` I opted to use drawstring instead but now I'm stuck with trying to get `JTextField` on. I don't know what I am missing.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

class main
{   
    public static void main (String Args [])
    {
        GUIwindow guiW = new GUIwindow();
    }
}

class GUIwindow extends JFrame
{
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    JTextArea screenArea = new JTextArea("", 10, 20);
    JScrollPane scrollBar = new JScrollPane(screenArea);
    
    GUIwindow()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,800);
        setTitle("Title here");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        screenArea.setLineWrap(true);
        screenArea.setEditable(false);
        
        
        grid.add(scrollBar);
        add(grid);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#0232ac"));
        g.fillRoundRect(100, 50, 300, 600, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("TitleonRect", 220, 80);
    }  
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not override the method `paint()` of JFrame.

Override the method `paintComponent()` of an element.

If you subclass JPanel, you can override its `paintComponent` method:

```
class GridPanel extends JPanel {
    GridPanel() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.decode("#0232ac"));
        g.fillRoundRect(100, 50, 300, 600, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("TitleonRect", 220, 80);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because your snippet adds only a textbox, what else are you expecting it to show?

Comment: JFrame doesn't have a paintComponent() method. You should create a JPanel, add components to this panel, and override the paintComponent() method of the panel. And add this panel to the frame. Also, always add the @Override annotation to methods that are supposed to override a method from the base class/interface.

Comment: Change the coordinates of your string, it appears. You get the idea, now it is oyur job to play with it to understand how it works to fit your needs.

Comment: @JBNizet isn't it what I did?

Comment: @Bobski change the coordinates for your string to 220 400, and you will see it :)

Comment: Yes, sorry. My comment was for Bobski.

Comment: nope nothing. I don't think its coordinates. The fillroundrect was a massive rectangle on my screen...now it doesn't show at all.

Comment: I tried that on my machine and I can the blue rectangle, the text, and the textbox. https://gist.github.com/jrm2k6/7398128 (exact code i am running)

Answer (score 1):

The `paint(Graphics g)` function is the one which paint your component and it's content with invoking fowllowing three functions in the order they are appearing:

- **`protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)`**: this one paint your component, e,g.:background
- **`protected void paintBorder(Graphics g)`**: this one paints the border of the component
- **`protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)`**: This one paints the children of the component in it

So, anything you are painting by overriding the `paint(Graphics g)` function, you should call these function as well with the order they appeared above inside the `paint()` function. Calling `super.paint(g)` will work, because it is calling the container's Super class(`JComponent` class)'s `paint()` function which is already invoking these three function.

But: why you are overriding this `paint()` function for just custom painting! put your custom painting code by creating a custom component extending `JComponent or JPanel` and implement `paintComponent()` function by overriding it and don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()`. If you need to have this custom component as frame's content pane: just set this pane `frame.setContentPane(customPane)`;

Check out [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's all explained in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29):

> public void paint(Graphics g)
>
> Paints the container. This forwards the paint to any lightweight components that are children of this container. If this method is reimplemented, super.paint(g) should be called so that lightweight components are properly rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `paint()` with `JFrame` because it's better to use `paintComponent()` on `JPanel` then add it to `JFrame`.

In the `paintComponent()` call `super.paintComponent()` to prepare the drawing surface to be painted.