# How to draw an image over JPanels

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing

I have a Battleship game in which I am trying to draw the ships, hits, and misses on the `Grid` object. `Grid` is an instance of JPanel with many `Blocks`. `Blocks` are JPanels also but are attributes of the `Grid`. The ships are being drawn on the Grid but under the Blocks. Is it possible to draw over the Blocks? I tried the Glass Pane and it didn't work too well. Any other solutions?

[image: This is how it looks now, the ship is at C3.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to draw over the Blocks? I tried the Glass Pane and it
>   didn't work too well. Any other solutions?

Yes, a non-recommended but sometime useful approach is to use an extended `JPanel` and override the `paint(Graphics g)` function:

```
Class MyGridPane extends JPanel
{

 @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g); // <----- don't forget to call this

       // then anything you draw will appear above the child component's 
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create(); // cloning to work, it is safer aproach
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.3f));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();// disposing the graphics object 
    }

}
```

Alternatively you may look into using `JLayeredPane` to work with a Panel containing your drawn image above the *target panel(Grid)*'s layer. 
Check out [**`How to Use Layered Pane`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: JavaFX has a large number of improvements over Swing/AWT - it's worth a look as it's the future of Java UI's and graphics.

Comment: I was doing the drawing using paintComponent(Grahpics g), but changed that to paint(Graphics g) and everything worked! Thank you! What is the difference between the two?

Comment: [check out my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889792/no-j-components-show-on-my-shape/19889924#19889924)

Comment: So by putting the painting code in paintComponent(), it was calling paintComponent and then paintChildren(), which paints the Blocks on the Grid. Great answer, thank you!

Comment: @rstumbaugh Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting is done in AWT & Swing

Answer (score 0):

> `Blocks` are `JPanels` also but are attributes of the Grid. The ships are
>   being drawn on the Grid but under the `Blocks`.

There's a sneaky way to achieve it, but you may need to change your base layout to `GridBagLayout`.

Basically, you want to add each `Block` to its own cell but `GridBagLayout` will allow you to add components that can expand columns and/or rows, allowing to add your ships that expand over `Blocks`.

This, of course, assumes you ships and effects are based on components